# IOKit Driver to create/register virtual storage device

Tags: c++, macos, driver, iokit

I am currently learning how to write os x kernel extensions (in Xcode) so sorry If I have any facts wrong. I am looking for an example of how I can write a IOKit Driver that can register a virtual storage device in the system (like a usb hard drive, usb stick or SD card etc..) that would show up as a normal device drive in finder, I believe it would be around the IOMedia area and use class IOBlockStorageDevice but Im not completely sure. I want the kernel to be able to handle all the functions like read and write actions, mounting and ejecting, etc...

In the very end I wanna create device driver to detect an android device (which uses MTP) and mount it as a storage device allowing users to read and write to it in finder and the driver will handle the read and write sending the data to the phone. (I know theres likely other drivers out there that do this but I would like to make my own) But for now I just wanna know how to make a driver that can generate a virtual usb drive.

Thankyou for putting up with me

Answer (score 2):

For example code of a virtual disk, the "Ramdisk" project from Chapter 14 of the [example code from the book](https://github.com/Apress/os-x-ios-kernel-programming) 'OS X and iOS Kernel Programming' by Ole Henry Halvorsen and Douglas Clarke is a reasonable starting point.

Instances of the `IOMedia` class are normally created automatically by the storage subsystem; you don't normally need to subclass it. Subclassing `IOBlockStorageDevice` is usually the way to go for block storage device drivers, whether they're virtual or physical. (For example, macOS's disk image (dmg) handling is implemented in `IODiskImageBlockStorageDeviceOutKernel`, also a subclass of `IOBlockStorageDevice`, while the USB mass storage driver is based on SCSI, so the `IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00` creates an `IOBlockStorageServices` which is in turn a subclass of `IOBlockStorageDevice`)

I should point out however, that for your ultimate goal, a block storage device is probably not a good solution. MTP is as far as I'm aware file based, and does not represent a block device. So for applications to see the files on the block device, you'd need to emulate some kind of file system backend inside your virtual block device driver, which is going to be unnecessarily complicated even if you pick something simple like FAT.

It's probably a better approach to implement this as a file system driver. FUSE would probably be a good starting point for this; if you find that overly limiting, you can always turn it into a "true" kernel based VFS kext.